# Copying file to Docker Container during Build but Process claims File Not Found

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, virtual-machine

I am using **Docker Toolbox** to run a Python API. My Docker-Compose for the Python API can be seen below:

```
flask-api:
    container_name: flask_api
    restart: always
    build:
      context: ./api/
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "5000:80"
    volumes:
      - ./api:/usr/src/app
```

The Dockerfile for this flask-api is found in the `./api` folder. The Dockerfile is:

```
FROM python:3-onbuild

RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY requirements.txt /usr/src/app

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

COPY . /usr/src/app

CMD ["python", "app.py"]
```

The `app.py` file can be found in the `./api` folder. However, given the Dockerfile and Docker-compose setup, running `docker-compose` finishes with the flask-api container crashing, claiming the "app.py is not found".

Somethings I have tried:

1. I converted the Python image to an Ubuntu image with the same Dockerfile, ran it in interactive mode, and found that the files were indeed copied over.
2. I ran the Python image in interactive mode as well, used `os.lisrdir()` to list files at the current directory, and once again found that the files were indeed copied over.

Any ideas on the cause of this issue? Please let me know if there is any other information I can report.

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce the error. In other words, this works for me.

Comment: Is your `docker-compose.yml` file in the same directory as `api`?

Comment: No, it is not. It is one directory above. I will provide any more information + setup that I can to help reproduce the issue, but I am not sure what more I can provide.

Comment: Can you try moving it to the same directory as `api`?

Comment: Try changing it to `CMD ["python", "/usr/src/app/app.py"]`. I would probably change python to be an absolute path as well, but that's just me

Comment: It seems to me like you are copying your app correctly into the image in the /usr/src/app directory. But afterward in your docker-compose you mount a local volume over your/usr/src/app directory, thereby losing your previously copied /app folder contents. Try removing the mounted volume '.:/app'.